# How do I add a class to a div if the item in ng-repeat is not valid?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use $invalid to add a class to a div when the input within the div is not filled out. However I just cannot work out the syntax.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="miniC">

    <form name="persondetails" novalidate>

    <div ng-repeat="account in myAccounts" ng-class="{'has-error': account.amount.$invalid}" >

        <input name="{{account.name}}" ng-model="account.amount" required="required"/>

    </div>

    </form>

</div>


function Account(nameArg, amountArg){
   this.name = nameArg;
   this.amount = amountArg;
}
```

The surrounding div needs to have class="has-error" when the inner item is not filled in. I have done similar on single bound elements just cant seem to get this working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$invalid` flag is not attached to the ngModel, but to the form controller (ngFormController).

In your example you're not demonstrating that you're even using ngForm, and you should, if you want angular to validate your form.

Next, you're trying to dynamically set the input's `name` attribute. ngForm won't like it because ngFormControll will be initialized before your expression is evaluated. 
Workaround is to wrap each ng-repeat iteration inside new ngForm (ngForm can be nested and it will just work) and name your inputs with some static string value (e.g. `name="amount"`).

So, you'll want your view written as:

```
<div 
  ng-repeat="account in myAccounts" 
  ng-class="{'has-error': form.amount.$invalid}" 
  ng-form="form"
>
  <input name="amount" ng-model="account.amount" required="required"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I updated my answer and now it works. I was actually using a form but left it out of the code snippet sorry. I tried what you suggested and it worked thanks!

Comment: @Exitos if Stewie's answer works, please mark this as answered so this question doesn't show up in the unanswered list.  Thanks.